# How to get past the ceiling monster?

Tags: candy-box-2

I understand that the trick would be to pass over the eggs and use anti-grav potions but i have no idea how to jump.

Comment: We basically have 6 answers that are exactly the same on this page so I wont add a 7th, but I wanted to add that I used the rocket boots in addition to unequipping all offensive gear to carefully fly between the Ceiling monsters and eggs. SPOILER ALERT: You can get the rocket boots from the third door of the desert fortress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unequip weapons and items that cast spells. You will walk over the eggs

Comment: I tried that, it'll jump over the first egg, drop from it and then destroy it. EDIT: Equipping the enhanced knight armor allowed me to pass on the eggs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To jump you need a pogo stick. This can be found by clicking the `*` that's visible in the mountain range on the world map.

Answer (score 2):

I beat it with a carefully-timed / luckily-timed obsidian wall. The ceiling monster got stuck on the wall and I killed it with ranged damage... the Monkey Staff and/or the random fireball shooting equipments.

Comment: You killed it? Did it drop anything?

Answer (score 1):

The Ceiling Monster is a peaceful but protective beast.

To safely get to the chest:

1. unequip anything heavy you might be wearing so that you can safely
   walk over the eggs without hurting them
2. unequip anything that casts spells automatically, you don't want
   anything hurting the eggs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to kill the ceiling monster, you don't want to do any damage to the eggs, so remove all damage doing weapons and anything heavy.

1. Unequip all weapons.
2. Unequip the obsidian crown with jaspers if you have it.
3. Unequip all armor.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily jump over the eggs with the pogo stick, then use a anti-gravity potion to  float across, but make sure that you don't have any weapons/equipment (Enchanted or not)

That can damage the eggs.